# Unable to use code from static zlib library in a qmake Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, zlib

I have to use zlib (ver 1.2.8, already compiled one from the official source) inside my DLL. I'm using static linking, but unable to use functions or objects from zlib - gives me "С2065 undeclared identifier". I'm using Qt 5.4.1 and compiler fom MSVS2013. This is my pro file:

```
QT       -= gui
TARGET = ZLIB
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += ZLIB_LIBRARY

ZLIBDIR += "Y:/Git/Modules/TestZLIB/Libs" #It contains zlib's dll, lib and def
INCLUDEPATH += $${ZLIBDIR}

win32 {
    LIBS += -L$${ZLIBDIR} -lzdll
}

SOURCES += \
    Library.cpp \
    myzlib.cpp

HEADERS +=\
    myzlib.h \
    myzlib_global.h \
    zconf.h \
    zlib.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

UPDATE:
Path to .lib, .dll, .def is Y:/Git/Modules/TestZLIB/Libs.

zlib.h and zconf.h is in project folder and also I've tried to copy them to Y:/Git/Modules/TestZLIB/Libs and connect them to the project from there, but it doesn't work for me.
Other source files are in Y:/Git/Modules/TestZLIB/TestZLIB.

Y:/Git/Modules/TestZLIB/TestZLIB - this is a project folder (sources, .pro file etc.).
Y:/Git/Modules/TestZLIB/Libs - this is folder with zlib's files.

What can I do to make it works?
Thank you!

Comment: `INCLUDEPATH += "Y:/Git/Modules/ZLIB/Libs"`... shouldnt it be `INCLUDEPATH += "Y:/Git/Modules/ZLIB/include"` or whatever?

Comment: @UmNyobe "Libs" is my custom folder where I put zlib's files. And "ZLIB" is my project's name (I know it's confusing, sory). So I think it should not =)

Comment: yes but are the header files and library files (dll\.lib)  in the same folder? Update your question with the full paths to a header file and to a library file

Comment: like Kuba said do not move header files from the original "zlib" around. And "project folder" is still vague. Provide a path.

Comment: @UmNyobe Now it has to be clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking questions, it's common courtesy to set them to be unambiguous. Even if your project is really named zlib, you should never ask a question with such a project name, since it's impossible to answer any questions about it without having to resolve ambiguity at every step. It'll also possibly confound the error messages you get. From now on, when talking of zlib, I'm talking of the compression library, not your project.

If the only compiler error is about unknown identifiers, then your problem isn't with the `.pro` file. The compiler simply doesn't see zlib's declarations. The following are possible mistakes:

1. You're not including zlib headers in your own files.
2. Your [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) clash with those of zlib and effectively hide the zlib header contents.
3. If you wrote your own `zlib.h`, it may be hiding zlib's own headers. You must rename it to something else if so.
4. If `zlib.h` and `zconf.h` come from zlib, they don't belong in your `.pro` file.

Make sure that neither is the case.

Comment: Your include guards clash with those of zlib and effectively hide the zlib header contents. - This was the answer for me, thank you very much!!!